# Difference between count(1) and count(*) in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Through multiple sources, books and through asktom I found there is no difference between `count(1)` and `count(*)`. somewhere I found `count(1)` is faster than `count(*)`.
But I really dont know how?
As for as I know `count(*)` counts the `rowid` and `count(1)` counts the 1 as the number of rows. since `rowid` is 18 digit character does it take more time? As far as I know whether size is 2 or 38 it doesn't matter for speed.

Can anyone of you please clear my doubt.

Comment: [According to this question at AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:40208915257337) there is no difference, and the optimizer actually changes `count(1)` to `count(*)` because the first means "count the rows where 1 is not NULL", while the second means "count the rows". TLDR: use `count(*)`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe `count(1)` used to be faster in older versions of Oracle. But by now, I'm pretty sure the optimizer is smart enough to know that `count(*)` and `count(1)` mean you want the number of rows and creates an appropriate execution plan.

Here you go:

```
create table t as select * from all_objects;

Table T created.

create index tindx on t( object_name );

Index TINDX created.

select count(*) from t;

  COUNT(*)
----------
     21534

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor( NULL, NULL, 'allstats last' ));

Plan hash value: 2940353011

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name  | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | Reads  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |       |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:00.01 |     100 |     93 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE       |       |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |     100 |     93 |
|   2 |   INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| TINDX |      1 |  18459 |  21534 |00:00:00.01 |     100 |     93 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

select count(1) from t;

  COUNT(1)
----------
     21534

Plan hash value: 2940353011

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name  | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |       |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:00.01 |     100 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE       |       |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |     100 |
|   2 |   INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| TINDX |      1 |  18459 |  21534 |00:00:00.01 |     100 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So not only is it smart enough to know it can use the index to optimize this query, but it uses the exact same execution plan for the different versions (the plan has value is the same).

Comment: As far as I know there was never a version of Oracle where counting some arbitrary literal was faster than the standard expression. I distinctly recall claims like this circulating around the Oracle 6 timeframe, and they were not true then either.

Comment: The execution plan wouldn't tell you the difference in detail of the `SORT AGGREGATE` operation. It could be quite different. For example, aggregating a `SUM(LN(expr))` can be orders of magnitude slower when [`expr` is of type `NUMBER` than `BINARY_DOUBLE`](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/09/11/oracles-binary_double-can-be-much-faster-than-number/), but you wouldn't see that in the execution plan.

Answer (score 5):

I think the origin of this rumour is the assumption that the database must internally expand `*` into the full column list, and so substituting some literal like `count('Dracula')` cleverly avoids this overhead. But it does not, and it never has. I first heard this around Oracle 6 in 1990 (another variation was that you should use the PK column), and it was not true then.

One of the standard proofs (apart from checking whether it actually makes any difference to performance, which it won't) is to check the 'predicates' section of an execution plan where `count(1)` is used in a predicate:

```
SQL> select dummy from dual group by dummy having count(1) = 1

SQL> @xplan
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
Compatibility is set to 12.2.0.0.0

Plan hash value: 795860295

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |      |     1 |     2 |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER               |      |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   SORT GROUP BY NOSORT|      |     1 |     2 |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL  | DUAL |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(COUNT(*)=1)
```

Notice that the optimiser has substituted `COUNT(*)`.

All `count(1)` does is give you more keystrokes to type and make you look like someone who believes rumours.

Comment: I personally use count(2), which makes it go twice as fast ;-)

Comment: @tbone: I use `count(-1)`, which has already finished counting before I started it.

Answer (score 5):

I've tested two simple queries calculating `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)` on 1M rows in Oracle and a few other RDBMS, and haven't found any differences in Oracle. [See this post for details](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/09/19/whats-faster-count-or-count1/).

However, in PostgreSQL 11.3, it seems that `COUNT(1)` is about 10% slower, because PostgreSQL doesn't transform the expression to `COUNT(*)`, and thus checks for nullability on each row when running `COUNT(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

count(1) and count(*) are now same in oracle both uses index if available and count Nulls too.
count(1) simply replaces rows data with 1 and then count number of 1's and count(*) counts rows may be on the basis of rowids.

Comment: Not just "now", they have always been the same.