# What is the difference between count(*) and count(2) in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, count, having-clause, sql-null

I'm looking at some SQL code and I'm trying to figure out what is the difference between count(*) and count(2) in oracle.

For Example

```
select id_number from person
where type_id = 0010
group by id_number
having count(2) > 1;
```

Comment: Someone is trying to intentionally obfuscate the code.  I wonder if the intention is really `count(*) > 2`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between count(1) and count(\*) in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51460770/difference-between-count1-and-count-in-oracle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both expressions produce the same result.

`count(<expr>)` takes in account all non-`null` values of `<expr>`. `2` is a literal, non-null values, so all rows are taken into account, just like `count(*)` does.

You could as well express this with `count(1)`, `count('foo')`, or any other (non-`null`) literal value.

I like `count(*)` better, because it is somehow clearer about what it does: every row is in the group is counted, regardless of the values it contains.

Comment: Yes: there is a myth that `count(1)` is faster than `count(*)`, because "`count(*)` requires that every column is read", which is not true. `count(*)` doesn't even require that the table itself is read in some cases.

Comment: @DavidAldridge: yes, most likely any decent database would optimize `count(<constant>)` as `count(*)` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

They mean something different:

- `COUNT(*)` counts returned **rows**.
- `COUNT(<expr>)` counts non-null **values**.

In this case you are using `COUNT(2)` where the expression is always not null. Therefore, it will result in the same value as counting rows.

Theoretically counting rows could be marginally faster since the data must be *counted as present*, but doesn't need to be really *inspected*. Therefore, when counting rows the engine doesn't need to *materialize* the column values in order to evaluate the expression, but just need to handle pointers.